# Bash Script parse files for multiple occurrence of string between pattern

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, awk

I am doing little text processing to find video content in html files uploaded by users. So we have defined a tag called "video" and users are supposed to put the video files like

```
<video> abcd.mp4 </video>
```

Presently I am using awk to extract the line which has video tag,

```
str=$(awk '/<video>/{flag=1;} /<\/video>/{print ;flag=0} flag { print }' file.html)
```

The output contains the tag too, so I do prefix and suffix removal to get the video file name. Its done like this,

```
prefix="<video>"
suffix="</video>"              
foo=${str#$prefix}
foo=${foo%$suffix}
```

But this will only work for files which have video tags used just once. For files with multiple usage of  tags the string returned by awk starts from the first occurence of `<video>` till the last occurence of `</video>`.

So my question how should I write a script which will at the end of it give me an array of all the strings between `<video>` and `</video>` tag. Also how can I change the

```
<video> abcd.mp4 </video>
```

to say

```
<media> abcd.mp4 </media>.
```

Comment: Can there be multiple lines between opening and closing video tags?

Comment: Yes it can be written in multiple lines too.

Comment: Your second (new) question has a different optimal answer than the first...

Comment: Post a representative sample input file and the expected output from that input. THINK about any edge cases you might encounter and include those.

Comment: @beroe I do need both the names of the string between the pattern as I have to do ffmpeg conversion of those video files and then in html file change existing video tags with a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get each tag by itself:

```
grep -Eo "<video>(.+?)</video>" myfile.html
```

To get just the text within the tags:

```
grep -Eo "<video>(.+?)</video>" myfile.html | sed -E "s|</?video>||g"
```

If the opening and closing tags are on different lines:

```
tr "\n" " " < myfile.html | grep -Eo "<video>(.+?)</video>" | sed -E "s|</?video>||g"
```

Example input:

```
This is a <video> video1.mp4 </video>  file with <other> <random> </tags>
<media> media1.mp4 </media> 
<video> video2.mp4 </video> 
<media>     media 2 with spaces 
and over 
multiple lines.mp4 </media>
```

Example output:

```
video1.mp4 
video2.mp4
```

To get both `video` and `media` tags (please specify in your original question):

```
tr "\n" " " < vid.html | grep -Eo "<(video|media)>(.+?)</(video|media)>"  | sed -E "s#</?(video|media)>##g"
```

Output:

```
 video1.mp4 
 media1.mp4 
 video2.mp4 
 media 2 with spaces      and over      multiple lines.mp4
```

For your second question, run the whole file through this command:

```
sed -E "s|(</?)video>|\1media>|g" vid.html
```

Comment: But that will replace all the occurence of word video in the file.

Comment: OK, I changed it to only match exact tags, and not `video>`

Comment: (@MrinalKumar You don't have to have rep to "accept" with the checkmark, if this answered your question. That will help us know that you got what you needed...)

Comment: I ran `tr "\n" " " < file.html | grep -Eo "<video>(.+?)</video>" | sed -E "s|</?video>||g" `  
for the file file.html

`$cat file.html`    
`<video> video1.mp4 </video>  
<media> media1.mp4 </media>  
<video>  
video2.mp4 </video>  
<media> media 2 with  
spaces and  
over multiple  
lines.mp4  
</media>`

but the output was

    video1.mp4  <media> media1.mp4 </media>  video2.mp4

Comment: Are you trying to filter video or media tags? You should do one (video) then convert and do the insertion of media tags afterwards.

Comment: My output seems to be different for your sample file, I am getting  `video1.mp4   file with <other> <random> </tags> <media> media1.mp4 </media>   video2.mp4`  as output when I run `tr "\n" " " < myfile.html | grep -Eo "<video>(.+?)</video>" | sed -E "s|</?video>||g"`. Any idea why that would be ?

Comment: Can you try with single quotes instead of double quotes on the `grep` and `sed`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
    stag = "<"  tag ">"
    etag = "</" tag ">"
}

pos = index($0,stag) {
    $0 = substr($0,pos+length(stag)) 
    rec = ""
    inTag = 1
}

inTag {
    if (pos = index($0,etag)) {
        rec = rec substr($0,1,pos-1) 
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",rec)
        print "<" rec ">"
        inTag = 0
    }
    else {
        rec = rec $0 ORS
    }
}
$ 
$ cat file
<video> video1.mp4 </video>
<media> media1.mp4 </media>
<video>
video2.mp4 </video>
<media> media 2 with
spaces and
over multiple
lines.mp4
</media>
$ 
$ awk -v tag="video" -f tst.awk file
<video1.mp4>
<video2.mp4>
$   
$ awk -v tag="media" -f tst.awk file
<media1.mp4>
<media 2 with
spaces and
over multiple
lines.mp4>
```

Change `print "<" rec ">"` to just `print rec` after you understand and are happy with what it's doing.